reference_wrapper in c++ containers
Consider following snippet:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x=3;
    int y=1;
    int z=2;
    cout<<(&x)<<' '<<(&y)<<' '<<(&z)<<endl;
    set<reference_wrapper<int>> a;
    a.insert(ref(x));
    a.insert(ref(y));
    a.insert(ref(z));
    for(const auto& i: a) cout<<i<<' '<<endl;
    y=10;
    for(const auto& i: a) cout<<i<<' ';
    return 0;
}

What would happen to underlying container when a property used by container for sorting is modified?

Edit1 : From what I can try by running code, ordering goes wrong but since it was holding a reference, value is correctly updated. So one should be careful when using reference_wrapper inside containers (specially where mutations can cause container to invalidate its assertions)?

you managed to break an invariant. Keys in std::set are supposed to be const. As with almost anything there are ways to bypass this restriction but what you get is a broken set.

concerning your "Edit1" please try to keep the quesiton concise. SO is not like a forum with back and forth discussion. It shouldnt be necessary to read the quesiton, read the answer, continue to read the question to grasp what is being asked here.

"Is it  bad practice..." is opinion based.

If you're going to use reference wrappers you might just as well store non-owing pointers (no reall semantic difference, and easier to use). The big issue with references (and pointers) is that it is very easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Imagine x, y, z being local variables of a function and you return the set of references... So no it is not bad practice but you need to be careful. function to sort the pointers

Note you probably don't want to use std::set but std::vector<int*>

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Obviously keys should be kept const. I'm just trying to say that since there is no restriction to key type one can get into this trouble. More, I'm trying to check should this be considered bad practice to have reference_wrapper in containers or should one be careful?

thats the actually interesting part of the quesiton to which I also do not have an answer. Note that std::set provides you no non-const access to the elements. std::set::iterator is a constant iterator. Further note that you are not actually modifying the elements, they are const, but you modify the objects they refer to. The issue is with the comparator. I am not aware of some formalism that requires that when you do  auto x = comp(a,b);, do something (but not insert nor remove elements),  auto y = comp(a,b); that x and y must be the same.

but someone else knows :D

Got it, thanks! @463035818_is_not_an_ai

Where did you learn #include <bits/stdc++.h>?  Block that site.  Burn that book.  Unfriend that friend.  Learn C++ from a good C++ book.


What would happen to underlying container when a property used by container for sorting is modified?

Any further use of the container, that requires the comparison of that element, has undefined behaviour, because you are violating this requirement:

For any two keys k1 and k2 in the same container, calling comp(k1, k2) shall always return the same value.

[associative.reqmts.general]

Got it, thanks! How can one avoid getting into these issue? Should we avoid using reference_wrapper in keys of associative containers and unordered associative containers?

If the answer to above is yes, then, shouldn't standard only should not allow it to be created in first place? One can be careful but I think it might be much easier to run into this issue in a large codebase.

@Rupa std::reference_wrapper is not magic. Anyone can create similar classes. The key principle is not to create dangling references. Current state of C++ cannot prevent user from doing that.

@Rupa If the standard blocked std::reference_wrapper in sets, then someone would just write lib::reference_wrapper. To block that, you'd have to ban any class with any pointer data members. You just have to be vigilant about modification

@Red.Wave the issue here is not dangling, but generally any indirection that would allow to modify what the comparator compares has the same problem.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai constness is just part of the problem; providing a proper comparator argument(e.g an address comparator) can solve the constness problem. The inherent problem of dangling cannot be solved, unless reference_wrappper is avoided.

@Red.Wave but the question is not about dangling reference. Sure there can be issues OP didnt encounter yet, and being aware of dangling references is important. Your comment reads as if avoiding dangling references would solve the issue with the broken sorting but it does not. Perhaps I am just overinterpreting, though that is what I refer to.

@Red.Wave it isn't limited to pointers and references, a mutable data member also isn't suitable for forming (part of) a comparison

@Caleth comparator must always be defined to avoid relying on anything mutable. But as I mentioned earlier, storing none-owning refrences - like std::reference_wrapper - is calling for dangling reference/pointer problems; none-owning references are only wellcome in immediately executed expressions and current specifications of C++ core cannot distinguish between them and the others.

@Red.Wave or you can be careful with lifetimes. OPs code doesn't have any dangling, because the ints outlive the set

@Caleth don't send a man to do a machine's job. Whenever you leave the responsibility to man, bugs appear. All those programming idioms are created to transfer the chore from man to machine. Otherwise there's no point in high level programming constructs.

@Red.Wave you seem to be arguing that references are dangerous. I agree, but sometimes you need reference semantics. Not meeting the requirements is also a bug.

@Caleth I am arguing that requirements can be met, but it doesn't prevent the bugs. Extensive use of std::reference_wrapper is a time bomb.
